# one file php working with two forms

Tags: php

i have two forms (formulaire.html) and (authentification.html), the first i used to lo signe up and the second i use to signe up.. and i have one classe  php that i develloped my two function for the two forms.. i used $_SERVER in if condition to separate the forms but it does't work ,
here is my php Class thanj you for help

```
<?php
include 'Admin.php';
include 'config.php';
class Register
{
public $conn;
function __construct()
{
$c=new config();
$this->conn=$c->connexion();    
}
function RegistrerAdmin($admin,$conn)
{
    $req="INSERT INTO `utilisateur`
   (`nom`, `prenom`, `age`,`login`, `pwd`,  `type`) 
    VALUES('".$admin->recupererNom()."','".$admin->getPrenom()."',
   '".$admin->getage()."','".$admin->login."',
    '".$admin->pwd."','administrateur')";
     $conn->query($req);
    }
    function sauthentifier($login,$pwd,$conn)
    {
        $req="select * from utilisateur where login ='".$login."' 
  AND  pwd='".$pwd."'";
   $res= $conn->query($req);        
    $valide=$res->fetchColumn();
    if  ($valide)
    {
        echo 'authentification rèussi ';
    }
    else 
        echo 'verifier login ou mdp'; 
    }
 }
$a= new Register();
$admin=new    Admin($_POST['nom'],$_POST['prenom'],$_POST['age'],
$_POST['login'],$_POST['pwd']);
if ($_SERVER['/Formulaire.html'] )
{
if($_POST['pwd']==$_POST['confirm']) 
{
$a->RegistrerAdmin($admin,$a->conn);
echo 'bienvenue'.$_POST['nom'];
}
else echo 'mot de passe  et confirm incorrecte ';
}
else if ($_SERVER['/authentification.html'] )
{
$a->sauthentifier($_POST['login'],$_POST['pwd'],$a->conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to echo

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and check whats in it after submit, then compare

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'your_url')
```

Or you can send something in `$_POST` to differentiate both form submission like:

Form1 submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="reg1_submit" value="Submit">
```

Form2 submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="reg2_submit" value="Submit">
```

PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['reg1_submit'])){
    if($_POST['pwd']==$_POST['confirm']){
        $a->RegistrerAdmin($admin,$a->conn);
        echo 'bienvenue'.$_POST['nom'];
    }
    else 
        echo 'mot de passe  et confirm incorrecte ';
}else if (isset($_POST['reg2_submit'])){
    $a->sauthentifier($_POST['login'],$_POST['pwd'],$a->conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/Formulaire.html'` or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/authentification.html'` to indicate current called php file instead of just calling `$_SERVER['/Formulaire.html']`

Also I'd recommend you to split actions code into three different files: one will contain your class code and two others - actions to execute on forms submission.